# Decryption Output has strange symbols

Tags: android, .net, encryption

I am working on encrypting (and later decrypting) strings in .Net and Java (on Android), using AES encryption , in the .Net side every thing is OK, in the Android(Java) side the output string of the posted code has unknown symbols.

```
String stdiv = "1234567890123456";
String txtinput = txtview1.getText().toString();
String mainkey = "0000999988887777";
byte[] key;
key = mainkey.getBytes("UTF8");
byte[] iv = stdiv.getBytes("UTF8");
byte[] input = txtinput.getBytes("UTF8");
Cipher cipher;
cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS7PADDING");
SecretKeySpec keyspec = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES" );
IvParameterSpec paramspec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keyspec, paramspec);
byte[] result = cipher.doFinal(input);
String str=new String(result,"UTF8");
txtview2.setText(str);
```

Comment: this code is for decryption? which value you want to decrypt and what should be the output?

Comment: If I'm not totally blind, this code only encrypts the string, so the "unknown symbols" in the string would be the expected output, atleast from what's coded above :)

Comment: The word "strings" worries me.  Encryption works on bytes, not character strings.  You need to explicitly state the conversion between your plaintext string and bytes.  You probably need to convert the encrypted bytes to Base64 for transmission and then you need to reverse the process (using the same byte to character conversion) when decrypting.  Check that you have done all that.

Comment: `String str=new String(result,"UTF8");` is a mistake and reveals a lack of understand of what the output of encryption algorithms is. It is most definitely not a string from a character set.